# como puedo mostrar el nombre y no el id de otro tabla relacionada con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy usando while para recorrer la tabla **producto** esta contiene la tabla **talla** , pero no quiero mostrar el **id**sino el nombre que esta en la tabla **talla** pero no se como¡? e intentado asi:

```
 <table>
    
    <?php while($pro = $productos->fetch_object()): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$pro->id;?></td>
            <td><?=$pro->nombre;?></td>
            <td><?=$pro->talla_id['nombre'];?></td>
            <td><?=number_format($pro->precio);?></td>
            <td><?=$pro->stock;?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

pero sale error, aquí esta el código funcionando pero muestra el id y no el nombre:

```
<table>
    
    <?php while($pro = $productos->fetch_object()): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$pro->id;?></td>
            <td><?=$pro->nombre;?></td>
            <td><?=$pro->talla_id;?></td>
            <td><?=number_format($pro->precio);?></td>
            <td><?=$pro->stock;?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Debería ver como traes tu data, lo mas probable es que tengas que hacer un join a la tabla talla para conseguir el nombre.